# Upload File from Project - Selenium WebDriver Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium

Do you know if I can upload a file to a webpage using Selenium WebDriver with VisualStudio10 but without writing the path of the position of the file in my computer. I mean, adding this file to the project and call it from code without writing File path. I need it for example if my tests are going to be run by people with different machines they dont have to re-write the file path with their own path, can directly upload from the project without modification. Dont know if this its clear, but I try. Thanks in advance!

ElBandido

Comment: @EIBandido: Is their any uniqueness between the different files which user will upload? Like the only file in the location or name of the file or etc ?

Comment: Hi Rupesh, yes Im trying to upload all the time the same file, just to verify its possible to do it, so Im always calling "Test.txt" combine with the directoryPath as TidusJar said below. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would configure the file to be Output when compiled.
You can do this by selecting the file in the Solution Explorer and opening the Properties panel.
Set the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`.

Set the `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`.

You can just reference the file like:

```
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string filePath = Path.Combine(folder, "file.txt");
```